# Count the number of files and folders containing a certain string

Tags: bash, grep, filenames, wc

Let's say I'm in the Desktop directory and want to count the number of files and directories whose name is `exam`. It should also count the files containing the string `exam`. So to sum it up I need to:

1. Count the directories with the name `exam`
2. Count the files with the name and content `exam`

Here is what I've tried so far.

```
ls -l | grep -r "exam" | wc -l
```

But this command counts only files with the content `exam`. 
What if I have a couple of directories: `exam1`, `exam2`, `exam3`, and a couple of .txt files `exam1.txt`, `exam2.txt`, `exam3.txt`, and want to count them?

Comment: By *files containing the string exam*, do you mean files whose filename contains `exam` (for example `exam1.txt`), or files whose content has `exam` in it?

Comment: In case of files both conditions should be met, example: filename: exam1; content: this exam was really difficult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `find`, treating directories and non-directories differently, getting the counts for directories and non-directories separately:

```
find . -name '*exam*' \
    \( \(   -type d -exec echo directory \; \) -o \
    \(    ! -type d -exec grep -q -wF exam {} \; -exec echo file \; \) \) |
sort | uniq -c
```

This would find things in or below the current directory whose names contains the string `exam`.  If the thing is a directory, then the string `directory` is outputted.  Otherwise, if the thing is a non-directory, and if its contents contains the *word* `exam`, then the string `file` is outputted.  The `sort` and the `uniq -c` at the end would sort and count the number of files and directories found that matched the criteria.

Note that the test on the names may match names that contain `exam` as a substring, as in `example` for example. The `grep` on the files uses `-w` which will make it more likely that a *word* is matched, and not a substring.

Comment: I think you need to put (escaped) parentheses around the parenthesized expressions. That's probably because the `-name` test is ANDed with next expression and this has a higher precedence than the following `-o`. When I tested your command (without the `uniq -c`), it returned also regular files without `exam` in their name as long as there was the word `exam` in their content.

Comment: Actually, I just read in the man page of *find* that `-a` **always** has higher precedence than `-o`, and if the operator between two expressions is missing, `-a` is assumed.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Thanks, added parentheses to avoid precedences issues.

Comment: Please test, as this may not find all of the files that you are looking for, so you may not get full marks for your homework.

Answer (score 1):

I have done by below 2 commands

To count directories

```
find  path -type d -iname "exam[0-9]" | wc -l
```

To count number of files  with condition it should have content exam in the file

```
find  path -type f -iname "exam[0-9]" -exec grep 'exam' {} \;|wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

For folders:

```
 ls -lR * | awk -F '[ /]' ' !/^-/ && !/^d/{if ($NF ~ "exam" ) print $NF}' | wc -l
```

For files:

```
 ls -lR * | awk  '/^-/ {if ($NF ~ "exam" ) print $NF}'  | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script achieves what you want:

```sh
i=0
for file in *exam*
do
  if [ -d "$file" ] || [ -n "$(sed -n '/exam/{p;q}' -- "$file")" ]
  then
    i=$((i+1))
  fi
done
echo "Number of files: $i"
```

It loops over all the files whose name contains `exam`, and for each such file it checks whether it is a directory or it contains the string `exam`, and if it does, the script increases the counter by one.

**Edit:** I probably misunderstood your question and you want to count directories and files separately. In that case, modify the script to

```sh
i=0;j=0
for file in *exam*
do
  if [ -d "$file" ]; then
    i=$((i+1))
  elif [ -n "$(sed -n '/exam/{p;q}' -- "$file")" ]; then
    j=$((j+1))
  fi
done
echo "Number of directories: $i"
echo "Number of regular files: $j"
```